# OSM tileserver on Ubuntu 16.04 - renderd doesn't start on reboot

Tags: openstreetmap, tiles, rendering

I have been able to setup a simple OSM tile server on Ubuntu 16.04. I followed this [brilliant tutorial](https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/openstreetmap-tile-server-ubuntu-16-04) and also made [some notes of my own](http://wordpress-dbauszus.rhcloud.com/osm-tileserver-on-a-vanilla-ubuntu-16-04-droplet/). This works alright but whenever I reboot the system renderd doesn't start.

I have been trying to [get this working with upstart](http://blog.systemed.net/post/6) but that doesn't work on my Ubuntu 16.04 setup.

Here renderd is running fine, I reboot and it's dead. Service renderd start and it's running again.

[image]

I have renderd.init in my SystemV init.d directory. Obviously some config must be wrong but I wouldn't know where to start.

Comment: I guess https://superuser.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for this question.

Comment: @scai is right, you're better off posting this question over at a place like http://askubuntu.com/. But in the meantime here are some places to get you started with answers: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9382/how-can-i-configure-a-service-to-run-at-startup, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-linux-service-to-start-automatically-after-a-crash-or-reboot-part-1-practical-examples. With Ubuntu 16.04 you'll probably be looking at integrating with systemd, but I've also had success using the `@reboot` flag in `crontab`

Comment: Upstart keeps logs in `/var/log/upstart`, is there any info for Renderd there? I have had Renderd fail to start because the socket directory didn't exist.